# Calling a variable from another file into a bash script

Tags: bash, variables, export

I've trawled through similar questions to this, but can't quite find something that works, and wondered if you could kindly help.

I am trying to execute the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {0..10000}
do
mysql --user=genome --host=genome-mysql.cse.ucsc.edu -A -D hg19 -e '
Select 
 S.name as rsID,
 S.chrom,
 S.chromEnd,
 S.chromStart,
 K.txStart,
 K.txEnd, 
 G.geneSymbol,
 G.kgID 
from snp138 as S
left join knownGene as K on
 (S.chrom=K.chrom and not(K.txEnd+1000000<S.chromStart or S.chromEnd+1000000<K.txStart))
right join kgXref as G on
 (K.name=G.kgID)
where
  S.name in ("snp_permutation"$i".txt")'| awk -F '|' '{print $1}' | sed 1d | awk '{print $7}' | sort -u > permutation"$i"_genelist.txt
```

Essentially, I have 10,000 files called snp_permutation"$i".txt, where i runs from 1 to 10,000. Each of these files is just a single line, and its only content looks something like:

```
rs16574876
```

For this script to work, I need the *actual content* of the files (e.g. "rs16574876" to go between the quotation marks in  S.name in ("snp_permutation"$i".txt")', rather than the name of the file itself.

Do I need to use source or export for this?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Save yourself a ton of trouble by starting small and building out. Currently you have to simultaneously debug bash, awk, sed and mysql. Instead start with something trivial like `i=1; echo 'The value is ("snp_permutation"$i".txt)'` and then solve each problem until you get it to write `The value is (42)`. But to answer your question: no, you do not need to (and can't) use source or export for this.

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
#!/bin/bash

template=$(cat <<'END'
    Select 
        S.name as rsID,
        S.chrom,
        S.chromEnd,
        S.chromStart,
        K.txStart,
        K.txEnd, 
        G.geneSymbol,
        G.kgID 
    from snp138 as S
    left join knownGene as K on
        (S.chrom=K.chrom and not(K.txEnd+1000000<S.chromStart or S.chromEnd+1000000<K.txStart))
    right join kgXref as G on
        (K.name=G.kgID)
    where
        S.name in (%s)
END
)

for (( i=0; i <= 10000; i++ )); do
    printf -v sql "$template" "$(< "snp_permutation${i}.txt")"
    mysql --user=genome --host=genome-mysql.cse.ucsc.edu -A -D hg19 -e "$sql" |
      awk -F '|' 'NR > 1 {split($1, a, " "); print a[7]}' | 
      sort -u > "permutation${i}_genelist.txt"
done
```

This uses `$(<file)` which is a bash builtin for `$(cat file)`

Comment: That looks promising - Will try that. Thank you.

Comment: I tried it for the first four permutations, and for each line, I get an error message: 
ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 1: Unknown column 'rs12683614' in 'where clause'
ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 1: Unknown column 'rs117744418' in 'where clause'
ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 1: Unknown column 'rs66991551' in 'where clause'
ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 1: Unknown column 'rs72795184' in 'where clause'
Any ideas?

Comment: Oh, the value is not quoted. In the template you would want the last line to read `S.name in ('%s')`, and you'd need to do more work to protect against SQL injection in the shell for loop.

Comment: That's great - seems to work perfectly. Thank you again, Glenn - much appreciated.

Comment: take sql injection seriously. a snp_permutations file containing `foo');drop table snp138;--` would be disastrous. http://bobby-tables.com